# Simple way to reverse dask distributed dataframe

Tags: python, dask

I tried to reverse the order of a dask dataframe using `[::-1]`, but got a `NotImplementedError` that you can only use `iloc` indexing like `[:, ['foo']]`

e.g

```py
tmp=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1], b=[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]))
tmp=dd.from_pandas(tmp, npartitions=4)
tmp[::-1]
```

How can I easily reverse the order of a sorted dataframe, without loading the entire dataframe in memory?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that leaves the index unchanged:

```
@dask.delayed
def reverse_pdf(pdf):
    '''delayed function to reverse a pandas dataframe'''
    return pdf[::-1]

# generating testdata
tmp=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1], b=[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]))
tmp_dd=dd.from_pandas(tmp, npartitions=4)

# reversing tmp_dd
ds = tmp_dd.to_delayed() # one delayed object per partition
ds = [reverse_pdf(d) for d in ds] # reverse each partition
ds = reversed(ds) # reverse the order of the partitions
tmp_dd_reversed = dd.from_delayed(ds) # construct a new dask dataframe
```

Comment: I have to change the return function to make it work `return pdf.str[::-1]`

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a decent way to do this, using an integer index and multiplying by -1.

```py
tmp=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1], b=[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]))
tmp=dd.from_pandas(tmp, npartitions=4)
tmp=tmp.reset_index()
tmp['index']=tmp['index']*-1
tmp=tmp.set_index('index')
tmp.compute()
```

Comment: If you're okay with negative indices, this is a decent workaround.

Comment: You can add the max of the absolute value of the indices to get a positive index